# Unsuccessful redirecting of servlet based using string query parameters

Tags: java, servlets

Situation: In the code below I'm attempting to learn how to use form parameters specifically redirecting Java servlets by propagating string query parameters.

Problem: I can't seem to figure out why I'm facing a problem with re-directing the user from the form i.e. index.html using the desired string query paramters to the correct page.

Below are the steps I took before posting this up:

- I made sure the URL pattern for the @WebServlet annotation is correct
  i.e. in my case /CityManagerWebStarter/mainmenuresponder.do
- I made sure my content-root when looking at the URL is correct i.e.
  /CityManagerWebStarter and I can confirm this as when I launch the
  following URL http://localhost:8080/CityManagerWebStarter/ it
  displays the index.html page as expected.

Below is my servlet code and following that is my index.html code and ListCities.html is an example of a page I'm attempting to re-direct the user to:

servlet code:

```
package company.citymanagerweb.servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class MainMenuResponder
 */
@WebServlet("/CityManagerWebStarter/mainmenuresponder.do")
public class MainMenuResponder extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

     /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public MainMenuResponder() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        String userChoiceSelect = request.getParameter("menuChoice");
        String[] userOptionsCBox = request.getParameterValues("adminoptions");

        StringBuilder params = new StringBuilder();
        String queryStringParams = params.toString();

        if(userOptionsCBox != null) {
            boolean isFirst = true;

            for(int i = 0; i < userOptionsCBox.length; i++) {

                // Build URL with string query parameters i.e. URL + ? + PARAM1 + AMAPERSAND + PARAM2
                // Arguments is value of the value attribute
                if(!isFirst) {
                    params.append("&");
                } else {
                    params.append("?");
                }

                if(userOptionsCBox[i].equalsIgnoreCase("useDB")) {
                    // append() argument is value of the value attribute belonging to the input attribute
                    params.append("useDB=1");
                } else if(userOptionsCBox[i].equalsIgnoreCase("sendEmail")) {
                    params.append("sendEmail=1");                   
                }

                isFirst = false;
            }

            queryStringParams = params.toString();
        }

        if(userChoiceSelect.equals("1")) {
            response.sendRedirect("ListCities.html" + queryStringParams);
        } else if(userChoiceSelect.equals("2")) {
            response.sendRedirect("AddCity.html" + queryStringParams);
        } else if(userChoiceSelect.equals("3")) {
            response.sendRedirect("DeleteCity.html" + queryStringParams);
        } else {
            response.sendRedirect("index.html");
        }

    }

}
```

index.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Welcome to the City Manager</title>
    </head>
</html>
<body>
    <form id="form1" method="post" 
            action="/CityManagerWeb/mainmenuresponder.do">
        <table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="width:100%" align="center">
                    <h1>Welcome to the World City Manager</h1>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h3>What would you like to do today?</h3>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select id="menuChoice" name="menuChoice">
                        <option id="1" value="1">
                            List Cities
                        </option>
                        <option id="2" value="2">
                            Add a new city
                        </option>
                        <option id="3" value="3">
                            Delete a city
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="adminoptions" id="optionDatabase" value="useDB" />Use Database<br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="adminoptions" id="optionEmail" value="sendEmail" />Send Confirmation<br>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input name="chooser" type="submit" value="Choose" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

ListCities.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Listing Cities</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table style="width:450px;">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:150px;"><b>COUNTRY</b></td>
            <td style="width:300px;"><b>CITY</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Russia</td>
            <td>Moscow</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>England</td>
            <td>London</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>United States</td>
            <td>Washington, D.C.</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>CityManagerWebStarter</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>citymanagerwebstarter</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>company.citymanagerweb.servlets</servlet-class>
  </servlet>  
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>citymanagerwebstarter</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/citymanagerwebstarter/mainmenuresponder.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>  
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Thanks for any suggestions/help.

Comment: What problem are you facing exactly? What do you expect to happen, what happens? Did you verify that the parameters are correct using a debugger?

Comment: remove the doGet method if you dont need it, it might solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fairly common problem I'm seeing these days is that people are using the latest IDE tooling that generates their web projects using the **Servlet 3.0** specification i.e. the files generated use the new `@WebServlet`, `@WebFilter` etc. annotations way of doing things against the traditional deployment descriptor `web.xml`. But, they follow these old **Servlet 2.x** tutorials online and end up configuring the same servlet twice; once with the annotations and once again in the `web.xml`. This would lead to your server responding in undefined ways and must be avoided.

So, you can safely get rid of the following from your `web.xml`:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>citymanagerwebstarter</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>company.citymanagerweb.servlets</servlet-class>
</servlet>  
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>citymanagerwebstarter</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/citymanagerwebstarter/mainmenuresponder.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The next issue is that your web application's *context root* is never a part of your servlet or filter's `url-pattern`. So, your annotation should be like

```
@WebServlet("/mainmenuresponder.do")
public class MainMenuResponder extends HttpServlet {
```

Lastly, though it works as is, your `form`'s `action` attribute shouldn't hard code the *context root* like that. I suggest you use a relative URL there as well.

```
<form id="form1" method="post" action="mainmenuresponder.do">
```

Notice, that unlike the servlets, you can't put a leading `/` in the `action` here.

Comment: Hi Ravi ... many thanks for the detailed reply .. the 1st two points you make were the errors ... I've made the changes and the redirect is taking place as expected .. also I've eliminated the content root in the form's action attribute .. once again many thanks

Answer (score 0):

If `citymanagerwebstarter` is the content root. It should not be part of the url parttern in `web.xml` and `@WebServlet` annotation.

Comment: hi Ramesh .. many thanks too .. you and the below poster were quite helpful